# Eclipse display view won't show

Tags: java, eclipse, view

I want to change some code while debugging. I have some breakpoints set. Now I want to use the display view, but it won't show up. As you can see in the picture, I am running in debug mode. **Window -> Show View** (doesn't show) also in **Window -> Show View -> Others**. I am using Eclipse 2018-12, I tried to restart Eclipse but it won't show, please help.

---

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: You use 'Debug Shell' for this in recent releases, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175408/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 yes this works!! ty very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Eclipse 4.8 (Photon) the display view is replaced by the 'Debug Shell' - see the [release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#debug-shell)